# What is the best way for implementing a simple and reliable security mechanism between jQuery and WCF without using SSL

Tags: wcf, security, jquery

what is the best way to secure communication between wcf ajax enabled services and ui implemented with jquery ajax in absence of SSL?

-- EDIT --

It's enough to have a reliable Authentication (for example just with a token) & Authorization (A simple customizable mechanism to allow us check a service permission on each service call. We know role-based).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question in that *this is what SSL is for.* Are you in a position where someone is demanding that you *not* use SSL?

Couldn't you argue that they are asking you for both "A and NOT A" in saying that you need security but can't use a secure protocol?

Comment: unfortnately we cannot have a ssl license, so i'm thinking about programming tricks. any idea?